# 2 x WD20EARS (2TB) Raid 1 via Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, raid

I'm planning on setting up a RAID 1 for storing data using Western Digital WD20EARS 2TB drives.

I will be using RAID 1 in Windows 7

Will I have any problems with the setup?

Is there anything I need to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since those are "advanced format" hard drives, you may have performance problems if you try and access data from XP or older OS's, also depending on your raid controller there could be performance issues with the advanced format drives. There is a jumper on the drive to set it back to the old format prior to setting up the raid array, or use the WD align tool after they have been formatted with the advanced format.

Here is some reading

http://www.wdc.com/en/products/advancedformat/

http://community.wdc.com/t5/Other-Software-Accessories/Disk-Formatting-Advanced-Format-Technology-Whitepaper-amp/m-p/1495

http://wdc.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/wdc.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=5324&p_created=&p_cats=185&p_cv=1.185&p_pv=2.294&p_prods=227,294#jumper